# JQPlot labelRenderer

Tags: javascript, label, rendering, vertical-alignment, jqplot

Can I please have some help to display text on the YAxis to be displayed vertically in a JQPlot. Here is my current code:

```
                {
                    label: 'Rating',
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Import these two scripts required by the label renderer

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great help. I was having the same issue, but did not realize I needed the textrenderer too.